# Loop through XML using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have this XML in a column in a MSSQL table

```
<QueryXMLData>
  <main ShowAllPhoneNumbers="yes">
    <C ID="5753768" HID="1" Name="Michael" SSN="xxxxxxxxxxx" PayType="" Status="Active" StatusID="1">
      <S ID="5483911" HID="3" Name="Ethan" SSN="xxxxxxxxxxx" CType="Subscription" TPID="21456" TPName="Outside" TPShortName="Out" Status="Active" StatusID="P" D="Y" Checked="yes" Found="yes">
        <TPIDs>
          <Phone TP="1122334455" />
        </TPIDs>
      </S>
    </C>
    <C ID="5670554" HID="1" Name="Susan" SSN="xxxxxxxxxxx" PayType="" Status="Active" StatusID="1">
      <S ID="5297452" HID="3" Name="Johnathan" SSN="xxxxxxxxxxx" CType="Outbound" TPID="110" TPName="Out" TPShortName="Inside" Status="Active" StatusID="1" D="Y" Checked="yes" Found="yes">
        <TPIDs>
          <Phone TP="3344556677" />
        </TPIDs>
      </S>
      <S ID="5297426" HID="3" Name="Brad" SSN="xxxxxxxxxxx" CType="Outbound" TPID="110" TPName="Out" TPShortName="Inside" Status="Active" StatusID="1" D="Y" Checked="yes" Found="yes">
        <TPIDs>
          <Phone TP="5566778899" />
        </TPIDs>
      </S>
    </C>
  </main>
</QueryXMLData>
```

I would like for it to return these columns:

```
Customer Name     Subscriber Name        TPID    Phone TP
--------------------------------------------------------------
Michael           Ethan                  21456   1122334455
Susan             Johnathan                110   3344556677
Susan             Brad                     110   5566778899
```

I have tried

```
SELECT value.value('(QueryXMLData/main/C/@SSN)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Customer1,
value.value('(QueryXMLData/main/C/S/@SSN)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Subb1
from #tmp
```

But I would like for it to loop through every value instead of me inserting which line it is supposed to extract from.

Comment: @MartinSmith I've updated the columns on which I would like the query to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to skin the cat...

```
SELECT
       n.value('../@Name', 'varchar(50)'),
       n.value('@Name', 'varchar(50)'),
       n.value('@TPID', 'varchar(50)'),
       n.value('(TPIDs/Phone/@TP)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
from #tmp
CROSS APPLY value.nodes('QueryXMLData/main/C/S') n(n)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=93e6c8e8374bf6a2ac2e55c99c744d65)

Comment: (no cats were harmed in the making of this answer)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help

```
Select CustName = x1.value('@Name','varchar(150)')
      ,SubsName = x2.value('@Name','varchar(150)')
      ,TPID     = x2.value('@TPID','varchar(150)')
      ,PhoneTP  = x2.value('TPIDs[1]/Phone[1]/@TP','varchar(150)')
 From  @XML.nodes('/QueryXMLData/main/*') lv1 (x1)
 Cross Apply x1.nodes('*') lvl2 (x2)
```

**Returns**

```
CustName    SubsName    TPID    PhoneTP
Michael     Ethan       21456   1122334455
Susan       Johnathan   110     3344556677
Susan       Brad        110     5566778899
```

Now, If your data is in a table ... lets assume a column called XMLData

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select CustName = x1.value('@Name','varchar(150)')
                      ,SubsName = x2.value('@Name','varchar(150)')
                      ,TPID     = x2.value('@TPID','varchar(150)')
                      ,PhoneTP  = x2.value('TPIDs[1]/Phone[1]/@TP','varchar(150)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('/QueryXMLData/main/*') lv1 (x1)
                 Cross Apply x1.nodes('*') lvl2 (x2)
             ) B
```